# R isn't displaying all observations

Tags: r, read.csv

I am  newbie in R programming. I hope to find some help here :)

I am having some trouble importing my csv file to R. The file has 13603 rows and 321 columns. However, when I Import this file and assign it, I get only 7790 observations of 321 variables.

```
all <- read.csv2("all.csv")
```

I am missing almost half my dataset. When I print the dataset `[ read.csv2("all.csv") ]`, I get the following comment :

> reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 6077 rows

Is there a way I can get all my observations imported in R?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check `tail(all)` or `all[7000:7790,]`  It is a print format option thing.  You can change the `options` to print more if you want

Comment: If you are using rstudio, please try `View(all)`

Comment: if you are new to R you should look at Rstudio which is a beautiful environnement to work with R and will allow you to do many thing easily, including visualisation of big data frame

Answer (score 1):

It is there in the `options`.  If we want to increase the number of rows to print from the default settings, change the `options` with the `max.print`

```
options(max.print = 1e6)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the error message

 reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 4675 rows

Comment: @A_shi  What error message?  If there is an error message, then there is something wrong on your R installation

Comment: Sorry, It's not an error message. It still says  " omitted 4675 rows "

Comment: @A_shi It is not an error message.  It is a warning.  I can't reproduce that warning.   I just showed a max.print value.  If your dataset is really big, then you need to increase the print value.  But, having said that, it is of no use to print all the values in the console.  Instead, write it on a  csv/txt file and then check the output

Comment: @A_shi  The reason is that `(13603 * 321) > 1e6
[1] TRUE`,  You may need to put a higher value i.e. `1e7` or so

Comment: I actually do not want to print it, when I try to Import my dataset and assign it in my data Environment, I can only see half of the data set when I run " view(all) "

Comment: @A_shi as I mentioned earlier, for this big of a dataset, you can check the `str(df)`, and other summary statistics for validating the data instead of the whole data loaded.  Even if you were able to load the full data, it would be slow

Comment: @A_shi You can check the `validate` package to see if that helps